# Changing IGrouping key type inside query builder

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
class Entity {
    public MyEnum Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

class FilterItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<Entity> entityQuery = _db.Entities;

IQueryable<IGrouping<string , Entity>> groupingQuery;

groupingQuery = entityQuery.GroupBy(f => f.Type);

var query = groupingQuery.Select(f => new FilterItem
{
      Name = f.Key, // Here the type error occurs
      Total = f.Count()
});

return query.ToListAsync();
```

Right now it throws an error that it cannot convert MyEnum to string. So I tries to do so:

```
groupingQuery = entityQuery.GroupBy(f => f.Type.ToString()); // Cannot call a function like that in a query builder.
```

but I found out that it is not possible when actually trying to run this part. My question is:

**Is there a way to convert the enum so it would match my declared 'groupingQuery' variable type?**

Or, maybe if the type of 'groupingQuery' would be

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<MyEnum , BucketEntity>>
```

then maybe it is somehow possible to do the conversion on Select?

```
var query = groupingQuery.Select(f => new FilterItem
{
      Name = f.Key.toString(), // This is what I would imagine in an ideal world
      Total = f.Count()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually **can** call `ToString()` on the key. However just in the `Select()` and not in the `GroupBy()`. Watch the writing of `ToString` (not `toString`) and it should work.

I tested it with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q = new Test[] { Test.One, Test.Two, Test.Two };
        var e = q.AsQueryable().GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Key.ToString(),
            Amount = x.Count()
        });

        foreach (var x in e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

enum Test
{
    One,
    Two
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
One
Two
```